# Fourier series with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have
$$U(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-t}(A_n\cos(n\pi t)+B_n\sin(n\pi t))\sin(n\pi x) $$ By using the initial condition,

$$U(x,0)=0, A_n=0 \; ,0\le x\le 1$$
therefore 
$$U(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-t}(B_n\sin(n\pi t)\sin(n\pi x))$$

Using the other initial condition, 
$$U_t(x,0)=x(1-x)\;, 0\le x\le 1$$
This leads to 
$$x(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\pi B_n\sin(n\pi x))$$

So I use Fourier series to find $B_n$

$$\frac{2}{n\pi}\int_{0}^1x(1-x)\sin(n\pi x) dx$$
This gave me the answer
$$B_n=\frac{-4\left((-1)^n-1\right)}{(n\pi)^4}$$

So does that mean
$$U(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-t}\frac{-4((-1)^n-1)}{(n\pi)^4}\sin(n\pi t)\sin(n\pi x)$$
assuming all my calculations are correct?

What I don't  understand is how finding the coefficient for $B_n$ after taking the partial derivative of $U(x,t)$ with respect to $t$ help find the $B_n$ for just $U(x,t)$.

Comment: Where can we see the differential equation ?

Comment: ohh sorry let me change the title as its misleading

Comment: The initial condition $U_t(x,0)=x(1-x)$ is defined  on what range of $x$  ?

Comment: the range of x is $0\le x\le 1$

Comment: I agree with your calculus and result.